# How to handle null value of date with number of days or months or year

Tags: oracle

I am creating a report for which I required to show expiry date but when the expiry date is null means I have to show numerical values like days, months or years

```
 Nvl(To_Char(b.Charter_Start_Date, 'DD/MM/RR') || '-' ||
       To_Char(b.Charter_End_Date, 'DD/MM/RR',Charter_Period_min || ' ' 
       ||Charter_Period_Max ) "EXPIRY DATE",
```

when the start date and end date is null means 
I have to show 30 days or 4 months or 2 years

Comment: hi, can you share the sample of expected output

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying. I mean - I understand the *words*, but not what's behind them. What do those "30 days **or** 4 months ..." mean? Why 4 months? Why 2 years? Why 30 days?

Comment: Actually i said that when date column has null value means i have to display like xx days or xx months or xx years

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you want to do, but your NVL() won't work in this case because the first argument is a string including `'-'` which will never be null. Try something like this instead.

```
CASE when b.Charter_End_Date is not null 
     then To_Char(b.Charter_Start_Date, 'DD/MM/RR') || '-' || To_Char(b.Charter_End_Date, 'DD/MM/RR')
     else Charter_Period_min|| ' ' ||Charter_Period_Max
   END "EXPIRY DATE",
```